# Ext JS 4.0.7 Load mask not working for Grid

Tags: extjs, extjs4

Load mask of a grid is not working which is triggered in button handler which is in the dockedItems of the same grid. (i am using Ext JS 4.0.7)

But in console,

```
viewareaGrid = Ext.getCmp('mva')
viewareaGrid.setLoading(true);
```

above code shows the load mask perfectly in console.

Below code is the view in which i am manually filtering the users.

filterFunction() will run for atleast 4 secs.

What could be wrong ?

```
Ext.define('AM.view.main.user', {
    id:'mva',
    extend:'Ext.grid.Panel',
    region:'center',
    alias:'widget.mva',
    store:'user',

    dockedItems:[

                {
                    id:'filter',
                    text:'Filter',
                    xtype:'button',
                    handler:function () {
                        var viewareaGrid = Ext.getCmp('mva')
                        viewareaGrid.setLoading(true);
                        filterFunction();
                        viewareaGrid.setLoading(false);
                    }
                }]

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of doing this is to create a callBack function to hide mask and execute it inside filterFunction. Also use 'defer' to call filterFunction to give browser breathing space to render the load mask.

Fiddle here: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2d8

Comment: What is the issue with the code which i have mentioned in the question. It should still work right? But fails.

Is it like, we have to umask always using callback function ??

Comment: The issue is, 'viewareaGrid.setLoading(false)' will get executed before the 'filterFunction()' returns... callback ensures the required code gets executed only after filterFunction finishes executing. (Updated the fiddle with log message)

Comment: @newmount I have the same problem but a minor change `this.setLoading(true);` is not working for me, works good in `console`

Comment: @yashhy have you tried defer executing the function which you execute after this.setLoading(true)

Comment: @newmount I couldn't get you I just asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21422199/extjs-setlodingtrue-not-working question regarding this

Comment: From the fiddle, if you notice console 'stop loading' gets triggered right after 'start loading' regardless of the time taken by the function which is getting executed in-between. This is because all three are getting executed sequentially. To avoid this (i.e) calling stop loading after the function finishes executing we have to use a callback function.

Comment: say to bind `defer` and `doFiddleStuff` over `this.setLoading(true);` so that `this.setLoading(true);` executes?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46298/discussion-between-yashhy-and-newmount)